# Comparing strings with xslt and sum the same that are equal

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml

```
<home>
<room name="Petter">
    <surface>200</surface>
</room>
<room name="Sara">
    <surface>50</surface>
</room>
<room name="Petter">
    <surface>100</surface>
</room>
```

With xslt:

How can I solve this question: I must sum all the surface elements that belong to Petter and belong to Sara (dynamically). i.e. Peter=300, Sara=50

I have to compare the `@name` and sum the surface that have the equal `@name`, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: This is a *grouping* question (FAQ).

Comment: If you're using XSLT 1.0, do a search for [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). If you're using XSLT 2.0, do a search for [xsl:for-each-group](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping). Give it a try. If you have trouble, come back and update your question with the XSLT that you tried and the desired output you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Could you post what output you expect?  I think this is pretty clear, but that will make sure that there is no confusion at all.

Comment: I want Petter 300 Sara 50

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to solve it using XSLT1.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/home/room[not(@name=preceding-sibling::room/@name)]">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(../room[@name=current()/@name])"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

We loop over each room whose name has not yet occurred (the first occurrence of each room) in order to get a unique list of the names.  For such room, we sum the rooms whose name is equal to the name we are working with.  This will output

```
Petter: 300
Sara: 50
```

There are other ways to do this grouping, for example *The Muenchian Method*, that relies on the **xsl:key** as well as the `key` and `generate-id` functions and is often more efficient than this method.  I'll leave that as an exercise if you wish to use that method.  I'm not sure if it is more efficient in this use case, however.

---

Using XSLT2, we could do this like

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="/home/room" group-by="@name">
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group())"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here we also loop over the room elements, but we can tell the XSLT engine to group them for us by name.  Then for each group, we output the name and the sum *of the group*.